# Reference request on symmetric polynomials

Tags: rational-functions, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

Let $e_k$ be the $k$th-degree elementary symmetric polynomial in $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ (and recall that $e_k=0$ if $k>n$).

I know very little about these polynomials.  I've just noticed this odd identity and wondered if it's a standard thing found in refereed sources or is generally known?

Consider the rational function
$$
\frac{e_1+e_3+e_5+\cdots}{e_0+e_2+e_4+\cdots}.
$$

The identity is that if $x_1=-1$ then the value of the rational function above is $-1$, so $-1$ is an absorbing element for this operation on $x_1,\ldots,x_n$.

**PS:** Second similar question: Is the fact that this operation on $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is associative widely known and in the literature?

**PPS:** While we're at it: Is there some standard name for this operation?

**PPPS:** Another number, $1$, is also an absorbing element, although $-1$ is the one that engaged my attention when I posted this.

Comment: I haven't seen it stated as an identity before, but it seems to make for a nice exercise in generating functions. The object $\Phi(t)=\prod(1+tx_n)$ I sense is a standard thing to look at, though, and this rational function happens to be given by the expression $\frac{\Phi(1)-\Phi(-1)}{\Phi(1)+\Phi(-1)}$ (suppressing the other variables). It is not clear to me though what you mean by the operation being associative.

Comment: "Associative" means what it usually means.  If there are just two variables, you get $x\circ y= \dfrac{x+y}{1+xy}$.  Then show that $(x\circ y)\circ z = x\circ (y\circ z)$.  Both are equal to $\dfrac{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_1 x_2 x_3}{1+x_1 x_2 + x_1 x_3 + x_2 x_3}$ $=\dfrac{e_1+e_3}{e_0+e_2}$. ${}\qquad{}$.